# Capture keypress event on series of <input> elements and sum the values

Tags: javascript, input, keypress

I have a series of input text elements with array-like names like `p_at[0][int], p_at[1][int], ...`. I need to catch an `onKeypress` event for every `input` in the page to make a sum.
Note that the inputs are dynamically generated. I tried to solve it in many ways but nothing worked for me.

```
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][65]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][66]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][67]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][68]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][69]">
    <input type="text"  value="0" name="sum[0]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][65]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][66]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][67]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][68]">
<input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][69]">
     <input type="text"  value="0" name="sum[1]">
```

Answer (score 1):

**No jQuery Answer**

```
var inputlist = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

var inputListener = function (evt) {
    //put the code that handles the event here
};

for( var i = 0; i < inputlist ){
    if( inputlist[i].type === "text" && inputlist.name.substr(0,4) === "p_at" ){
        if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
            elem.addEventListener("Keypress",inputListener ,false);
        else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
            elem.attachEvent("onKeypress", inputListener );
    }
    }
}
```

**With jQuery Answer**

```
$('input[type="text"][name^="p_at"]').keypress(function(evt){
    //put the code that handles the event here
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do from the description you've given... I get the feeling that using a bunch of inputs is not the way you want to go. also you'll probably want to edit your HTML to make it easier. Any way you could give a little bit less abstract of an example?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a div, e.g. `<div id='wrap'>` and assign the event handler to that div:

```
$("#wrap").keyup(function() {
    calculate the sum
})
```

Complete working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fkpFX/

Comment: He hasn't tagged the question with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It's very inefficient to add event listeners to every input. Instead use a delegate (putting one listener on the parent). Add an event listener to the `<form>` (I called it `sums` in my example).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/KWTLu/

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'sums' ).addEventListener( 'keyup', function ( event ) {

    if( event.target.name.substr( 0, 4) == 'p_at' ) {

        var index = event.target.name.substr( 5, 1 ),
            inputs = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[name^="p_at\[' + index + '"]' ),
            value = 0;

        for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
            value += window.Number( inputs[i].value ) || 0;
        };

        document.getElementsByName( 'sum[' + index + ']' )[0].value = value;

    };

}, false );
```

HTML:

```html
<form id="sums">
    <input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][65]">
    <input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][66]">
    <input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[0][67]"><br />
        <input type="text"  value="0" name="sum[0]"><br />
    <input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][65]">
    <input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][66]">
    <input type="text"  value="1" name="p_at[1][67]"><br />
         <input type="text"  value="0" name="sum[1]">
</form>
```